# Inequality on Cardinality of a set

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Consider the set $\mathcal{X} := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0, \ \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2 = n  \}$.

Prove that, for all $k \geq 1$,
$$ \max_{ x \in \mathcal{X} } \ \text{Card}\left( \{ i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\} \mid |x_i| > k   \} \right) \ \leq \ \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k^2} \right\rfloor, $$

where $\text{Card}(\cdot)$ denotes the cardinality of a discrete set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words: If $r$ out of the $n$ numbers $|x_i|$  are $>k$, then $r\le \frac n{k^2}$. But that is clear as these $r$ numbers alone contribute more than $rk^2$ to $\sum x_i^2$, which should equal $n$.
This shows that we can improve $\le\lfloor\frac n{k^2}\rfloor $ to $\le\lceil \frac n{k^2}\rceil -1$.